# Do 'init.ps1' scripts still works when installing a NuGet package?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, nuget, nuget-package

This question might be a little outdated, but **does *'init.ps1'* scripts still works when installing a nupkg?**

I was trying to use *'install.ps1'* and *'uninstall.ps1'*, but after a little bit of research I've seen that those files stopped working with **Visual Studio 2017 (which is the version of Visual I'm currently using)**, but I have not found any recent information about *'init.ps1'* (being the most recent from 2017 or 2018).

**My script is working correctly when executed by itself** but seems like it's not getting called on the package install.

In the case that *'init.ps1'* still works here's my *'.nuspec'* file, am I doing something wrong?:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2013/05/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>NugetTry</id>
    <version>0.0.142</version>
    <title>NugetTry</title>
    <authors>rwpk9</authors>
    <description>Description</description>
    <copyright>Copyright ©  2023</copyright>
    <dependencies>
      <group targetFramework=".NETFramework4.7.2">
        <dependency id="EntityFramework" version="6.4.4" />
        <dependency id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.es" version="5.2.9" />
        <dependency id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="13.0.2" />
      </group>
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
  <files xmlns="">
    <file src="init.ps1" target="." />
  </files>
  <powershell xmlns="">
    <scripts>
      <base><![CDATA[init.ps1]]></base>
    </scripts>
  </powershell>
</package>
```

My *'init.ps1'* is at the same path as the *'.nuspec'*.

Comment: You should be getting a warning that the init.ps1 is in the wrong path. Are you using some super old version of nuget.exe?  https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/blob/419ab86c016778ee3aeab40ea6fee879c09c7365/src/NuGet.Core/NuGet.Packaging/Rules/InitScriptNotUnderToolsRule.cs#L26

Comment: @zivkan I don't have access to nuget.exe itself, I'm using it trough Azure Pipelines

Comment: AzDO has [a task to "install" nuget.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/nuget-installer-v0?view=azure-pipelines) and you can tell it what version to use. Someone in my team (I work on NuGet) talked with the AzDO team to ensure they default to a recent version, but a few months ago, if you didn't use the NuGetInstaller task, you'd end up with an ancient version of nuget.exe that's years and years old. I don't know if this has been resolved yet, so it may be that you're using an old version of nuget.exe that's missing warnings that catch some common mistakes

Comment: Also, init.ps1 was never run on package install. It's only run when the Package Manager Console (PMC) is open, in case your package adds PowerShell commands to PMC, like EF6 does.

Comment: I'll check it again then, taking all your commets as answers, thanks a lot! I'll make you know if I solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `init.ps1` file needs to be in a `tools/` directory, not the package root. So, the zip file's central directory record has a path of `tools/init.ps1`

Comment: Thanks for your time and answer, I think it's just deprecated in VS2017.

Comment: it still works, otherwise EntityFramework 6 wouldn't work.

Comment: I'll check it again then taking all your commets as answers, thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi zivkan, if possible, could you please share a complete example on this if init.ps1 is possible to use? Thanks. :)

Comment: @IvanGlasenberg here's an example that works: https://nuget.info/packages/EntityFramework/6.4.4

Answer (score 0):

I think this no longer works.

I already put the init.ps1 to the tools directory and then configured the .nuspec, after that, package the package.

But if I install the package at the first time in the solution, I didn't see my powershell script run.

From the Nuget Product Team member:

https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4318#issuecomment-343255043

> powershel script is deprecated for package reference, we don't
> recommend people to use script in their packages.

I think this is deprecated.

Comment: I've read that post too thats why I was skeptical that it would work, I've also found a post saying it was just the `install.ps1` and the `uninstall.ps1` that were deprecated in VS2017 so I decided to ask here for someone to confirm, I'll mark your aswer as solved just for future people in the same situation to find out. Thanks for your time!

Comment: it still works, otherwise EntityFramework 6 wouldn't work.

Comment: install.ps1 is deprecated, and PackageReference projects won't trigger it, but init.ps1 should still work.

Answer (score 0):

Init.ps1 execution seems to be no longer supported for NuGet CLI. It is however still supported if you install a package using the NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio.
Here are the outputs from VS when installing manually

```
Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'NugetTest2.1.0.0' with respect to project 'NugetTest2', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5'
Gathering dependency information took 418 ms
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'NugetTest2.1.0.0' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Resolving dependency information took 0 ms
Resolving actions to install package 'NugetTest2.1.0.0'
Resolved actions to install package 'NugetTest2.1.0.0'
Adding package 'NugetTest2.1.0.0' to folder 'D:\src\NugetTest2\packages'
Added package 'NugetTest2.1.0.0' to folder 'D:\src\NugetTest2\packages'
Added package 'NugetTest2.1.0.0' to 'packages.config'
Executing script file 'D:\src\NugetTest2\packages\NugetTest2.1.0.0\tools\Init.ps1'...
Successfully installed 'NugetTest2 1.0.0' to NugetTest2
Executing nuget actions took 3,19 sec
Time Elapsed: 00:00:04.6619063
```

Notice how it did execute the script file. On the other hand, when using the CLI to install it, no script execution is done. Here is the output,

```
Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'NugetTest2.1.0.0' with respect to project 'D:\src\test\', targeting 'Any,Version=v0.0'
Package NugetTest2 from source D:\src\NugetTest2 gathered from cache.
Total number of results gathered : 1
Gathering dependency information took 18 ms
Summary of time taken to gather dependencies per source :
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'NugetTest2.1.0.0' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'     
Resolving dependency information took 0 ms
Resolving actions to install package 'NugetTest2.1.0.0'
Resolved actions to install package 'NugetTest2.1.0.0'
Retrieving package 'NugetTest2 1.0.0' from 'D:\src\NugetTest2'.
Adding package 'NugetTest2.1.0.0' to folder 'D:\src\test\'
Added package 'NugetTest2.1.0.0' to folder 'D:\src\test\'
Added package 'NugetTest2.1.0.0' to folder 'D:\src\test\' from source 'D:\src\NugetTest2'Successfully installed 'NugetTest2 1.0.0' to D:\src\test\
Executing nuget actions took 69 ms
```